# Prevent multiple checks of a CheckedListBox -- a better way?

Tags: winforms, checkedlistbox

I've got this CheckedListBox in a Windows form, and I don't want multiple checks. I can prevent multiple *selection* by setting the SelectionMode to "One", but there's no corresponding CheckMode that can be set to one.  If I set CheckOnClick to "true", when the user selects an item, it checks, but selecting or checking another item does NOT clear the previous check. So I can end up with all boxes checked and only one item selected.  I get around this with this code:

```
private void chkOtherNameType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkOtherNameType.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < chkOtherNameType.Items.Count; x++)
        {
            chkOtherNameType.SetItemChecked(x, false);
        }
        chkOtherNameType.SetItemChecked(chkOtherNameType.SelectedIndex, true);
    }
}
```

But is there a better way?

Comment: There is a different way, whether it is "better" is impossible to guess.  You normally use the ItemCheck event.  If e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked then simply uncheck everything.

Comment: I hoped you would respond, @HansPassant, you seem to know a lot about WinForms.  I think I see the way you're indicating, and it may be no "better", but I encourage you to provide it!  I know this is somewhat of a closeable question, worded the way it is, but in a way, it provides an answer embedded in the question, in case someone is trying to figure out how to deal with what I was.